# Create a function that manipulate values from Fahrenheit to Celsius from JSON

Tags: javascript

I have a large JSON file that displays 365 days of weather forecast. I want to create a function that converts the temperature that is currently in Fahrenheit to Celsius.

The data looks similar to this

```json
[{
apparentTemperatureHigh: 17.29
apparentTemperatureHighTime: 1514844000
apparentTemperatureLow: 4.51
apparentTemperatureLowTime: 1514887200
apparentTemperatureMax: 17.29
apparentTemperatureMaxTime: 1514844000
apparentTemperatureMin: -2.19
apparentTemperatureMinTime: 1514808000
temperatureLow: 12.23
temperatureLowTime: 1514894400
temperatureMax: 18.39
temperatureMaxTime: 1514836800
}]
```

How would I best loop through this and display in Celsius?
The sum for `Celsius = (Fahrenheit - 32) * 5/9`

Comment: Show us what you have tried. SO isn't a free code writing service

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This can be done using `Array.map`.

```js
const input = [{
  apparentTemperatureHigh: 17.29,
  apparentTemperatureHighTime: 1514844000,
  apparentTemperatureLow: 4.51,
  apparentTemperatureLowTime: 1514887200,
  apparentTemperatureMax: 17.29,
  apparentTemperatureMaxTime: 1514844000,
  apparentTemperatureMin: -2.19,
  apparentTemperatureMinTime: 1514808000,
  temperatureLow: 12.23,
  temperatureLowTime: 1514894400,
  temperatureMax: 18.39,
  temperatureMaxTime: 1514836800
}];

const output = input.map((forecast) => {
  const entries = Object.entries(forecast).map(([ key, value ]) => ([ key, key.toLowerCase().includes('time') ? value : (value - 32) * 5 / 9 ]));
  return Object.fromEntries(entries);
});
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Doesn't work, you're converting the times too.

Comment: The Array.map is largely irrelevant; mapping through the object pairs, more so.

Answer (score -1):

Well, the best would be, as you said, looping the values and apply your sum for the calculation.
The best thing performance wise would be to run everything async (if supported)

Comment: On the contrary, running everything aysnc would probably have negligible to a small impact on performance unless the amount of data to be processed is absolutely massive AND is done in WebWorkers (or multiple threads on NPM)

Comment: This is because javascript async is in general still single threaded.